# Using a single HashMap for multiple inherited classes

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap

I have this base abstract class:

```
public abstract class GameObject {

    private int _position;
    private int _resourceId;
    private ObjectType _objectType;

    public GameObject(ObjectType type, int position, int resourceId){
        _objectType = type; _position = position; _resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    public ObjectType getObjectType(){
    return _objectType;
    }

    //Some more methods...
}
```

Then I have some more classes which inehrit from `GameObject`:

```
public class Snake extends GameObject{

    private SnakeType _snakeType;

    public Snake(ObjectType type, int position, int resourceId, SnakeType snakeType){
        super(type, position, resourceId);
        _snakeType = snakeType;
    }

    public SnakeType getSnakeType(){
        return _snakeType;
    }

    public int getDamage(){
        return _snakeType.getMask();
    }
}

public class Home extends GameObject{
    public Home(ObjectType type, int position, int resourceId) {
        super(type, position, resourceId);
    }
}
```

My problem is, I have to have a collection of these objects in a `HashMap<Integer, GameObject>...so I Can have access to theire shared members like`position`and`resourceId`.

How can I achive that? If not, what would be the alternative?

**UPDATE**

It turned out that I can actually put any subclass of `GameObject` in `HashMap`.

```
int id = 1;
_hashMap.put(id++, new Home(ObjectType.HOME, id -1, resHome ));

_hashMap.put(id++, new Normal(ObjectType.NORMAL, id -1, resNormal));

_hashMap.put(id++, new Snake(ObjectType.SNAKE, id -1, resSnakeOne, SnakeType.A));
```

But now when I want to get items back, I face problem:

```
Snake snake = _hashMap.get(3);
```

compiler complains that it supposed to find `GameObject` but not `Snake`...whats the problem here?

I have the hash map in another class (in a class that inherits from BaseAdapter) and I want to add all objects to this hashmap so I can later provide the `getView` with the position and resource of objects as drawable.

Using CAST I can convert it back, but it kills the whole idea....I want to point to all game objects using the Key of the hashmap....at the moment I have to remember which Key refers to which kind of object:

```
GameObject obj = _hashMap.get(3);
Snake snake = (Snake) obj;
```

snake.getSnakeType();

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: You are using `HashMap<key, value>` you can always access the value object by finding it by the key. Please can you be more specific ?

Comment: You could have a `protected static HashMap<Integer, GameObject>` field in your GameObject. What do you mean by single HashMap exactly?

Comment: You have to cast the result from `get`.  (To be on the safe side you may first want to get the result as a GameObject, test `instanceof Snake`, and only then cast your result object to the Snake var.

Comment: "at the moment I have to remember which Key refers to which kind of object" - That's why there's `instanceof`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thats what I did but then I have to remember which Key refers to which type of object

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am asking how can I have a base class that I can drive from it and use it in a single hashmap for all of drived classes

Comment: Why isn't it enough to write `GameObject obj = hashMap.get(3);` ?  Having written that, you can do stuff like `obj.getPosition()` (if you have written such a method), `obj.getResourceId()` and so on - anything that you have listed in the `GameObject` class.  The things you can't do are the methods that only exist in one subclass or another.  And if you have a method declared (possibly as abstract) in the `GameObject` class, and implemented separately in each subclass, you can use that too.  So you are really not limited in what you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose shared members with a higher visibility than private - which is what you currently have the _position and _resourceId fields visible at.  This means that those fields are only visible within the class GameObject - not even subclasses of GameObject can access them, let alone clients of GameObject references.

Ideally, your superclass, which you should be treating as an interface with a partial implementation, will have some accessor methods for properties you want to expose to clients of any GameObject implementation.  I would suggest adding the following to GameObject if you wish to expose those properties to any class in your program, including a client of your `Map`

```
 public int getPosition(){
    return _position;
 }

 public int getResourceId(){
    return _resourceId;
 }
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html for more detail on access modifiers in the context of inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you please check my update to the question?>

Comment: that update has nothing to do with the original question... if you want to work with Snake specific references, then type your HashMap as <Integer,Snake> and not <Integer,GameObject>.  Otherwise, what would be helpful in your case is to learn how to program to an interface and not an implementation - which is what I gather you want to do with your GameObject class.  Research polymorphism, starting with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html .